# Why are ESLint errors not highlighted in the code?

Tags: javascript, configuration, eslint, webstorm

ESLint errors are displayed in the console, but nothing is highlighted in the code itself. I guess the problem may be that I switched to another device and did something wrong in the project.

My IDE - WebStorm, going to "Settings -> Language -> JavaScript -> ESLint", selected the Manual ESLint configuration item and specified the paths to ESLint and its configuration in the project, also added the ESLint plugin, but all this did not fix my problem.

I have a very large `eslintsrc.json` file and everything works fine for my colleagues, also everything worked for me on my old laptop, so the problem is definitely not in the configuration. It seems to me that when I cloned the project from the repository to a new laptop, I did not add something in the WebStorm settings.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please wait while we look into the crystal ball to see what's wrong on your computer. In case you don't want to wait any longer, consider adding a bit more information and details to the question :-)

Comment: @Davi, I added some information) unfortunately, I do not know what the problem might be and therefore do not understand what information might be useful

Comment: "and everything works fine for my colleagues, also everything worked for me on my old laptop" - so everyone involved has tested the same `eslintsrc.json` file?

Comment: @FiddlingAway yes, so I'm sure the problem is not with eslint, but something else.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache? Both for ESLint and Webstorm, I mean. The reason I'm suggesting this quite banal - the laptop might be new, but not *new* (out-of-the-box). It might have had a previous user, so something might be left in the cache which is causing the issues.

Comment: @FiddlingAway, the laptop is new out of the box and clearing the cache does not solve my problem

Comment: What happens if you try automatic ESLint configuration, and then test your previous code (drawer-nav.tsx)? Or, what happens if you leave your config file as it is (so, no auto ESLint configuration), and start a new project in which you'll intentionally introduce JS errors, just to see if they'll be highlighted?

Comment: @FiddlingAway, regardless of what I choose, mistakes are also not highlighted if I intentionally make them.

Comment: I'm all out of ideas, then. I suggest that you edit your question, and mention all of the things that didn't work, and that we tried ((json file tested on other computers, your laptop being brand new, automatic configuration, new project and intentional errors, etc)) - perhaps someone else would be able to come up with a solution to this.